# Prevent passing temporary object as an argument to a function

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue

Suppose I have this:

```
template <typename CharType>
class StringView
{
private:
    const CharType* m_String;
    size_t m_Length;

public:
    template <typename CharTraits, typename StringAlloc>
    inline StringView(const std::basic_string<CharType, CharTraits, StringAlloc>& str) :
        m_String(str.c_str()), m_Length(str.length())
    {
    }

    inline const CharType* Str() const
    {
        return m_String;
    }
};
```

Is there a way to prevent construction from a temporary `std::string`? That is:

```
std::string GetStr()
{
    return "hello";
}

int main()
{
    std::string helloString = "hello";
    StringView<char> str1 = helloString; // This is ok
    StringView<char> str2 = GetStr();    // I want this to be a compiler error

    std::cout << str1.Str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << str2.Str() << std::endl;   
}
```

I need this to work on at least VS 2015 C++ compiler. Platform specific hacks are welcome if there's no portable solution.

Comment: To what end do you desire to prevent construction from a temporary `std::string`?

Comment: @Altainia: because `str2.Str()` invokes UB with dangling pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may delete the constructor:

```
template <typename CharTraits, typename StringAlloc>
StringView(std::basic_string<CharType, CharTraits, StringAlloc>&&) = delete;
```